# PBXCp Error..Storyboard: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Very weird error. My storyboard is working fine, but I'm missing my xml file. I found a solution here: http://www.pashik.com/2012/08/25/xcode-error-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file-or-directory/

The article suggests I delete the app contents in derived data folder at “~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_APP_NAME

This solution seems to be working for others. My problem is that when I go to that folder, the files are missing..

So how would I go about deleting such files? Are the files hidden? Do I need to delete them via terminal?

Here's the error x-code gave me:

```
CpResource /Users/---/Desktop/Storyboard /Users/---/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_name-dvzijgdixqofgwdwwnjpvdnicolv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App-name.app/Storyboard
    cd /Users/---/Documents/App-Name
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/---/Desktop/Storyboard /Users/---/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-Name-dvzijgdixqofgwdwwnjpvdnicolv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App-name.app

error: /Users/---/Desktop/Storyboard: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 92):

In project setting click the build phase tab , there you find Copy Bundle Resources delete the file which provide you the error, it really solved my problem

Comment: Or, if it's a framework making the issue, delete it from "Embed Frameworks"

Comment: I deleted the file from the Bundle Resouces and it worked. Xcode should have done it intelligently, which it didn't.

Comment: You sir deserve a medal! Thanks!

Comment: It is good to highlight that the file might not be colored in red under Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: Thank you sir. You just save me :D

Comment: Thanks you very much