# XCode Cocoapods ChameleonFramework : No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios-simulator, osx-chameleon

I am unable to run my app on the Simulator, getting the below error

```
error: ....Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChameleonFramework.framework: No such file or directory
```

Below is my pod file

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'ChameleonFramework'
```

I am new to Xcode and I am unable to figure out what went wrong and how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you installed cocoapods? If not, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238/1025063)?

Comment: Yes, I did. As you can see there are no issues with other pods.

Comment: Remove ChameleonFramework framework from Podfile and Install Cocoapods. Add ChameleonFramework and install cocoapods again. If possible show your logs once you install pods with ChameleonFramework framework.

Comment: try this command in terminal "pod deintegrate" and then after "pod install" and "pod update" and then check if any issue please let me know.

Comment: @ravi.p : Please find the solution in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue
Go to Project Settings -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks -> Removed Chameleon Framework.

Reference : [PBXCp Error..Storyboard: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914244/pbxcp-error-storyboard-no-such-file-or-directory)

Look for the comment by the user 'brimstone'

Comment: No one else will be able to run your app, because the framework is not part of the bundle.

Comment: @Kentzo : Could you please elaborate ? I am not sure what you are saying.

Comment: Third party frameworks (i.e. those that are not normally present on user's machine ) have to be embedded inside the bundle to be available on user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project -> Target -> General tab -> Linked frameworks and libraries click on plus button and add the framework.

[image]

Or

Go to project -> Target -> General tab -> Build Settings Type Search path

[image]

Comment: I have found the solution, please check the answer